# Import big sql file with mysql-node-importer

Tags: mysql, node.js

I must use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mysql-importer
Here is my code:

```
importer.config({
 'host': config.connections.statshop.host,
 'user': config.connections.statshop.username,
 'password': config.connections.statshop.password,
 'database': 'w2r_' + params['login']
});
importer.importSQL('db/_referentiel_web2roi.sql')
```

The _referentiel_web2roi.sql sql file is very long but only the first table structure was imported. Why ? How to fix the problem ?

I repeat, I must use mysql-node-importer

Comment: Try looking for errors by adding a .catch